# Base R hist() function generates histograms with incorrect frequencies

Tags: r, histogram

I'm new to R and am trying to generate simple histograms for presentation to students. I've simulated a dataset with 10 variables, five of which contain negative values and five of which contain positive values.

Below is the data as shown in SPSS (easier to see than in R):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eDX8.png)

The variables are setup in pairs where each variable contains the exact same integers, except one contains negative values and the other positive (e.g., neg var = -4, -6, -7, -3, -2; pos var = 4, 6, 7, 3, 2). Each variable set has a different amount of skew.

I've done this to showcase to students positive vs. negative skew (and so they can play around with the data themselves).

The problem is that when I generate histograms using Base R functions the histogram containing positive values is different to the one containing negative values (in that the frequencies across bins are different). After checking the raw data, it seems the negative histograms produce the correct frequencies while the positive ones do not (they seem to be adding extra counts in some bins out of nowhere).

Examples are given below (produced using neg/pos variable sets and identical code except for variable name changes):

[image]
[image]

Code:

```
hist(Skew_Data$Neg_Normal_Within0.5)
your text`hist(Skew_Data$Pos_Normal_Within0.5)
```

Alternative code:

```
hist(Neg_Normal_Within0.5, prob=T, ylim=c(0, .2)) 
lines(density(Neg_Normal_Within0.5,na.rm=T))           
curve(dnorm(x,mean=mean(Neg_Normal_Within0.5,na.rm=T), 
           +             sd(Neg_Normal_Within0.5,na.rm=T)), add=T, col='red') 

hist(Pos_Normal_Within0.5, prob=T, ylim=c(0, .2)) 
lines(density(Pos_Normal_Within0.5,na.rm=T))           
curve(dnorm(x,mean=mean(Pos_Normal_Within0.5,na.rm=T), 
            +             sd(Pos_Normal_Within0.5,na.rm=T)), add=T, col='red')
```

More obvious discrepancies are seen in the graphs below:

[image]
[image]

Code:

```
hist(Skew_Data$Neg_ModerateSkew_0.5to1)
hist(Skew_Data$Pos_ModerateSkew_0.5to1)
```

Alternative code:

```r
hist(Neg_ModerateSkew_0.5to1, prob=T, ylim=c(0, .1)) 
lines(density(Neg_ModerateSkew_0.5to1,na.rm=T))           
curve(dnorm(x,mean=mean(Neg_ModerateSkew_0.5to1,na.rm=T), 
            +             sd(Neg_ModerateSkew_0.5to1,na.rm=T)), add=T, col='red') 

hist(Pos_ModerateSkew_0.5to1, prob=T, ylim=c(0, .1)) 
lines(density(Pos_ModerateSkew_0.5to1,na.rm=T))           
curve(dnorm(x,mean=mean(Pos_ModerateSkew_0.5to1,na.rm=T), 
            +             sd(Pos_ModerateSkew_0.5to1,na.rm=T)), add=T, col='red')
```

No matter if I use the code or alternative code, the neg and pos histograms are not identical even though they should be.

What I have found is that ggplot produces correct and identical histograms for my data:

[image]
[image]

Code:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(Skew_Data, aes(x = Neg_ModerateSkew_0.5to1) )+
 geom_histogram(binwidth = 5)

ggplot(Skew_Data, aes(x = Pos_ModerateSkew_0.5to1) )+
 geom_histogram(binwidth = 5)
```

But I thought I'd post regardless and ask if anyone knows what's going on here as it seems that the hist() function is simply producing incorrect graphs.

Thanks,

Jay

I tried to generate histograms with sets of identical variables and expected the graphs to be identical. The graphs were not identical, indicating the hist() function is not operating correctly.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Jay.  Just a note that images of data are usually not ideal - see here: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I'll extend _"not ideal"_ to say that unless truly trivial, I spend no time trying to transcribe data into something usable. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 for why images of data/code is not good, then please [edit] your question to add the output from `dput(x)` (or `dput(head(x,10))` or something) for each dataset you need us to use. Please keep them small and "complete" (representative enough to get what you need).

Comment: Also, please see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for how to format questions well. The presence of `\`your text\`` in numerous locations and yet the lack of any other "code block" is really an eyesore and makes it very difficult to read what you're trying to do. A code _block_ (multiple lines) starts with a triple backtick `\`\`\`` on its own line, then lines of code, then the triple-backtick `\`\`\`` again; an inline code _snippet_ uses single backticks. I think everything here should be in blocks. (Thanks to @PaulStaffordAllen for doing it for you.)

Comment: You have data points falling on the edges of your histogram bins - try including the `right = FALSE` argument with one set (positive or negative) and see if that helps https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.6.2/topics/hist

Comment: Keep in mind that histograms are univariate visualizations for continuous data. Your examples all use integers which are acting more like discrete data. There are edge causes when creating bins when you have values falling on breaks. If you have count data, you should consider using bar charts instead.

Comment: Read in detail the way to set bin "edges" in `hist`

Comment: The Real Lesson Here (TM) is: don't start using a tool to teach with until you truly understand the tool.   There are plenty of apps that can create histograms;  if you are intimately familiar with, e.g., MATLAB or Excel , just use that until you are comfortable with R.

Comment: Carl Witthoft - A sensible suggestion. Unfortunately, this assumes everyone has the freedom to use the software of their choosing when teaching, which is of course not true. Great Lesson otherwise, though.

Comment: Apologies to PSA and r2Evans, it's my first time posting so was unsure of the exact format. MrFlick and Paul, thank you very much for your answers, they really helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
# Reproducible example:

set.seed(250)
Pos_ex = sample(1:20, 20, replace = TRUE, prob = seq(1, 20, length.out = 20))
Neg_ex = Pos_ex * -1
                

# basic plots (don't appear to match)
hist(Pos_ex, breaks = 10)
hist(Neg_ex, breaks = 10)
```

[image]
[image]

```
# now amend the negative data to use the left boundary as the inclusion insgead of the right:
hist(Neg_ex, breaks = 10, right = FALSE)
```

The amended plot is a mirror of the first.
[image]